# Get LongListSelector's selected index through context menu

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm working with a LongListSelector that has a context menu attached to it as part of the ItemTemplate in the XAML. One of my context items is an edit option. In the click event of that option, I want to get the LongListSelector's index of the item being edited (aka the selected item), so that I can use it later. However, I'm having problems getting it to work. I've tried the following two things:

```
LongListSelector selector = (sender as MenuItem).DataContext as LongListSelector; 
int selectedIndex = selector.ItemsSource.IndexOf(selector.SelectedItem);
MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0}", selectedIndex)); //What's the index?
```

However, this always returns -1.

I've also tried accessing the list directly instead of through the sender, as below:

```
int selectedIndex = listTypedNotes.ItemsSource.IndexOf(listTypedNotes.SelectedItem);
MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0}", selectedIndex)); //What's the index?
```

This also returns -1.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out the answer.

```
 NoteData data = (sender as MenuItem).DataContext as NoteData;
 int selectedIndex = App.ViewModel.TypedNote.Items.IndexOf(data);
```

So, I basically asked my MenuItem to give me the information from the selected item of the LongListSelector, which is a NoteData item. Then, I got the index of that item, to give me the selected index!

Comment: Cool, can you explain to us how you found the answer and how it solves the problem? Also mark your own answer as accepted when you are for sure that it is the right answer, :).

Comment: Sure! So, I basically asked my MenuItem to give me the information from the selected item of the LongListSelector, which is a NoteData item. Then, I got the index of that item, to give me the selected index!

Comment: Lol I meant post it in your answer silly, not the comments :P, but this works too.